# What is the translator pattern in elm?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, reactive-programming, message, elm

In the [elm git book](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/) an architecture is described wherein child components generate messages which are disseminated via the main update function, eventually being handled by the appropriate update function in a child component. How does the translator pattern differ from this and what are the use cases of each pattern. Please provide a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a nested "component" with an `update` function, you will need to make sure the parent passes through the child Msgs and Cmds. The git book [outlines this with a simple example](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/02-elm-arch/07-composing-2.html) (where this code is in the parent, and `Widget` is the child):

```elm
type Msg
  = WidgetMsg Widget.Msg

update message model =
  case message of
    WidgetMsg subMsg ->
      let
        ( updatedWidgetModel, widgetCmd ) =
          Widget.update subMsg model.widgetModel
      in
        ( { model | widgetModel = updatedWidgetModel }, Cmd.map WidgetMsg widgetCmd )
```

The above will be necessary *any* time a child has an `update` function. However, the in the above example, the parent never knows or cares what child messages are being communicated to the child.

But now, consider the case that a parent needs to know about a Msg generated by a child. For instance: a game where a nested child component needs to communicate with a parent that the game is lost.

The [Translator Pattern](https://medium.com/@alex.lew/the-translator-pattern-a-model-for-child-to-parent-communication-in-elm-f4bfaa1d3f98) is useful when a parent component needs to react to a message returned from the child update function. Here is the basic structure of the update function in the linked example:

```elm
GameMsg internalMsg -> 
  let
    (game_, cmd) 
       = Game.update internalMsg model.game
  in
    { model | game = game_ } ! [ Cmd.map gameTranslator cmd ]
```

Notice that it looks a lot like the earlier `update` example; the main difference is that rather than mapping the `Cmd` directly to a blind parent `Msg` (*blind* in that the single `WidgetMsg` of the first example only passed around the child `Msg`), the `gameTranslator` mapping function allows you to map to one of the parent messages.

It may be helpful to read the [Translator Pattern Blog Post](https://medium.com/@alex.lew/the-translator-pattern-a-model-for-child-to-parent-communication-in-elm-f4bfaa1d3f98) in its entirety. It was written for Elm 0.17 so there are a few syntax changes, but the general idea still holds.

Comment: would it be `= Game.update internalMsg model.game ` instead, @ChadGilbert

Comment: Good catch! Yes, it would, and I fixed the example. I had copied it verbatim from the blog post.